# How to solve this error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized using Dropbox developer API

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dropbox-api

I have configure dropbox developer API in c#. and pass token and secretkey in below method.

```
OAuthToken oauth = new OAuthToken(DropboxAccessToken,DropboxAccessSecretKey);
var api = new DropboxApi(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, oauth);'''
var account = api.GetAccountInfo();
```

Last statement raise "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" this error. 
Please help me how to solve this and please let me know if any missing condition or steps.

Comment: Are you using [Dropbox.NET](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet) for this?

Comment: No, this is old one i am using dropbox 1.0.0.0 version

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you shared, it looks like you're trying to use OAuth 1 with Dropbox API v1. (OAuth 1 uses separate access token key and secrets parts, whereas OAuth 2 uses a single bearer access token. Also, the `GetAccountInfo` method name indicates Dropbox API v1.)

Dropbox API v1, along with the use of OAuth 1 with it, are retired now. You should instead use [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) with OAuth 2. For .NET, we recommend using [the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet). It includes instructions for getting started, full documentation, and example apps.

Comment: Ok. I am using latest dropbox version 4.0.0.0.
              `using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("TokenNumber"))
              {
                    var full = dbx.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();                      
              }`
But var full return this statement or error  : 
            `Id = 6, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}".`

Please help me anything missing statement or steps regarding Dropbox setup.

Comment: @Rushik This is a different issue so I recommend opening a new question. At a glance though, it may be because you're not `await`ing `GetCurrentAccountAsync`, which is an async method.